# Use Ajax to stop loading subsequent modal if there is an error in form data

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a multi-step form on my website which is made up of a series of modals. When I click next, I trigger the next modal and submit form data. I am trying to set up validation on these modals, where I either stop the activation of the next modal in the sequence, or reload the current modal if there is missing data. In my ajax call I can show that an error is present, but when I use `$('#Modal_2_Toggle').modal('show');` to try to reload the modal where the error took place, my code still passes the user to the next modal in the sequence. I am looking for help with blocking the loading of the next modal until `data.error` is false. Here is my HTML for the modal in question:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_2_Toggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="Modal_2_ToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="Modal_2_ToggleLabel">Frage 2</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="progress">
                          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 18%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">18%</div>
                        </div>                        
                        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data", id="form_2">
                            {{ form_2.csrf_token }}
                            <p>
                              <br>
                                {{ form_2.consumption.label(class="form-label") }}
                                {{ form_2.consumption(class="form-control form-control-sm", id="consumptionInput") }}
                            </p>
                            {{ form_2.submit(class="btn btn-primary", id="form_2_submit", hidden="true") }}
                            <br>
                        </form>
                        <div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary modal_btn" data-bs-target="#Modal_1_Toggle" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Vorherig</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary modal_btn" data-bs-target="#Modal_3_Toggle" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" form="form_2" id="modal_2_confirm">Weiter</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form_2').on('submit', function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            data : {
                consumption : $('#consumptionInput').val(),
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/test'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            if (data.error) {
                $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
                $('#Modal_2_Toggle').modal('show'); <- I ASSUMED THIS WOULD RELOAD THE MODAL
            }
        });
        
        event.preventDefault();
        
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your multi-step form approach is viable with your needs.
Perhaps you would reach your goal more easily and directly with one of the current JavaScript frameworks such as Angular, React, Vue or Svelte.

Nevertheless, the following example uses a single modal dialog with integrated slides, which can be activated and deactivated one after the other. It solves your problem that the next step cannot be called until the previous one has been completed correctly. The error code returned by the server determines the behavior mentioned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      form[name^=form-] {
        display: none;
      }
      form[name^=form-].active {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

            <form
              action="/ep1"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
              name="form-1"
              class="active"
            >
              {{ form1.csrf_token }}
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  {{ form1.some.label(class="form-label") }}
                  {{ form1.some(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                {{ form1.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
              </div>
            </form>

            <form
              action="/ep2"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
              name="form-2"
            >
              {{ form2.csrf_token }}
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  {{ form2.thing.label(class="form-label") }}
                  {{ form2.thing(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-prev">Previous</button>
                {{ form2.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
              </div>
            </form>

            <form
              action="/ep3"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
              name="form-2"
            >
              {{ form3.csrf_token }}
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  {{ form3.more.label(class="form-label") }}
                  {{ form3.more(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-prev">Previous</button>
                {{ form3.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(() => {
        let currentSlide = 0;
        const slides = $('form[name^="form-"]').toArray();
        $(slides).each(function(i) {
          $(this).submit(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            const form = $(this);
            const formData = new FormData(form[0]);
            $.ajax({
              url: form.attr('action'),
              data: formData,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              type: 'POST',
            }).done(function(data) {
              form[0].reset();
              form.removeClass('active');
              currentSlide = (i + 1)%slides.length;
              $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
              if (currentSlide === 0) {
                $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
              }
            });
          });
        });

        $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
          $(slides[currentSlide]).removeClass('active');
          $(slides[currentSlide = 0]).addClass('active');
        });

        $('.btn-prev').each(function() {
          $(this).click(() => {
            $(slides[currentSlide]).removeClass('active');
            for (currentSlide -= 1; currentSlide < 0; currentSlide + slides.length);
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'your-secret-here'

class Form1(FlaskForm):
    some = StringField(
        validators = [
            DataRequired()
        ]
    )
    submit = SubmitField()

class Form2(FlaskForm):
    thing = StringField(
        validators = [
            DataRequired()
        ]
    )
    submit = SubmitField()

class Form3(FlaskForm):
    more = StringField(
        validators = [
            DataRequired()
        ]
    )
    submit = SubmitField()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form1 = Form1()
    form2 = Form2()
    form3 = Form3()
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.post('/ep1')
def ep1():
    form = Form1(request.form)
    if form.validate():
        # Handle form data here!
        print(form.some.data)
        return '', 200
    return '', 400

@app.post('/ep2')
def ep2():
    form = Form2(request.form)
    if form.validate():
        # Handle form data here!
        print(form.thing.data)
        return '', 200
    return '', 400

@app.post('/ep3')
def ep3():
    form = Form3(request.form)
    if form.validate():
        # Handle form data here!
        print(form.more.data)
        return '', 200
    return '', 400
```